# How do I keep tabs in my active window with VS Code?

Tags: macos, mac, visual-studio-code

I'd like to open a tab and then have it stay there, but now I open a tab and then it disappears.

This is my workflow-

1. Cmd + P to find a file
2. Cmd + S to anchor the file into my window
3. Cmd + P to find another file

To speak to step two, the name for the file is in italics until I click cmd + s.

Right now, when I get to step three and open a new file, it replaces the initial file.'

I'd like to open a new file and have it open alongside the original file.

Answer (score 3):

In VS Code, clicking once on a file opens it in a temporary tab.
The idea is that if you are looking into multiple files while searching for
something, you can do it this way without opening all of them.

If you want to open a file in a new tab that persists until closed manually,
**double click** on the file.

To persist a tab that was previously created as a temporary tab is also
done by double-clicking on the tab.
Note that temporary tabs have an italics title, while normal tabs do not.

Comment: What's unusual is that the italics goes away after I press cmd + s but the file is still ephemeral

Comment: I'm literally unable to open another file without the initial one closing no matter what I try. The keep open option when I right click the name is greyed out

Comment: The above was Windows-oriented, I don't know how it works exactly on the Mac.